# Uniqueness of gradient

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

We say that $ u: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is
differentiable at $ x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ if there exists $ p \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ such that
\begin{equation}
u(x) = u(x_0) + \langle p , x -x_0 \rangle  + o(|x-x_0|)
\end{equation}
as $ x \rightarrow x_0 $. Here the "little o" notation has its usual meaning. Show that if there exist such $p$, then it is unique, this is, if
\begin{equation}
u(x) = u(x_0) + \langle q , x -x_0 \rangle  + o(|x-x_0|)
\end{equation}
then  $ p=q. $

Comment: What have you tried/where are you stuck?  This should be very straightforward - subtract the two expressions and simplify, then conclude $p=q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by icurays1 subtract the two equation and get $$\tag{1}\Big\langle p-q,\frac{x-x_0}{|x-x_0|}\Big\rangle=\frac{o(|x-x_0|)}{|x-x_0|}$$

Fix $v\neq 0$ and take $x=x_0+tv$ in (1), then we have $$\tag{2}\Big\langle p-q,\frac{v}{|v|}\Big\rangle=\frac{o(|tv|)}{|tv|}$$

By letting $t\rightarrow 0$ in (2) you can conclude that $\Big\langle p-q,\frac{v}{|v|}\Big\rangle=0$. Because the only restriction in $v$ is $v\neq 0$, this implies $p=q$.